# How to sign message in Python Web3 - AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sign'

Tags: web3.py

May I know why this is not working? `eth.accounts.sign`

Because every time I run my code below, it shows error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'sign'
```

Thanks:

```
    from web3 import Web3
    from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
    matic = "https://polygon-rpc.com/"
    
    web3matic = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(matic))
    
    if web3matic.isConnected():
        print("Web3 is connected")
    web3matic.middleware_onion.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
    
    signature = web3matic.eth.accounts.sign("msg", "privatekey")
    print(signature)
```

Comment: There are a few mistakes with your code, check the documentation (https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web3.eth.account.html?highlight=sign#sign-a-message) use web3.eth.account and not web3.eth.accounts , and encode the message prior to calling sign on it with encode_defunct(text="the message content").